# how to sanitise string that may contain some HTML tags like <b><i><u> but not contain <script> tag and encoded scripts to avoid xss

Tags: php, xss

i want to sanitise html but i want to keep tags like

```
<b> </b>
<i> </i>
<u> </u>
<code> </code>
```

but i want to remove tags like

```
<script></script>
```

and encoded unsafe html like

```
<IMG SRC=X ONERROR="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">
```

how to do it without using library.

Comment: The examples on that question can be bypassed easily with `<script >` or `<script>\n`. They are not at all suitable for avoiding xss. I would reconsider using a library to do this safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xss sanitize**

Sanitize for HTML output

```
function h($string) {
    return htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

Sanitize for JavaScript output

```
function j($string) {
    return json_encode($string);
}
```

Sanitize for use in a URL

```
function u($string) {
    return urlencode($string);
}
```

Usage

```
echo h("<h1>string from database</h1><br />");
```

or `strip_tags` I use for description.

```
$allowed_tags = '<div><a><href><br><p><span><img>';
echo strip_tags($row->description, $allowed_tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//allow the tags you want to keep

$ALLOWED_TAGS = '<p><h1><h2><h3><h4>';


//strip_tags function will remove the tags that you don't need

echo strip_tags('Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>', $ALLOWED_TAGS);
```

Comment: This is not good enough as the user might send <p onmouseover="alert(1);"> tag which strip_tags() will keep.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove all tags.
set the allowed tags as different container, ie: [b]bold[/b] and later on replace them with the allowed tags, this will help you to avoid unwanted HTML attributes that a user might send.